# Enzyme Shallow not finding a react-bootstrap Component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, chai

Below is a Sign In React SignIn Component made by using Redux-forms

```
const renderInput = ({input,label,type,placeholder}) => {
  return (
      <div>
    <Form.Label>{label}</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control type={type} placeholder={placeholder} { ...input}/>
    </div>
  )
}

export let signInForm = props => {

    const { error,handleSubmit , pristine , submitting } = props

    return (
        <Container className="justify-content-md-center">

       <Alert variant="primary">Sign in here if you already have an account</Alert>

        <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <Form.Group>           
            <Field name="email" component={renderInput} label="Email" type="email" placeholder="Email" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group>   
            <Field name="password" component={renderInput} label="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button type="submit"  disabled= { pristine || submitting }>Sign In</Button>

        </Form>

        </Container>

    )
}



export default signInForm = reduxForm ({
    form : 'signIn'
})(signInForm)
```

My enzyme-shallow test for this

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import {signInForm  as SignIn} from './SignIn';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import { expect } from 'chai';


describe('Test SignIn component', () => {
  it('Test click event', () => {
    const mockCallBack = jest.fn();

    let wrapper = shallow(<SignIn onSubmit={mockCallBack}/>);

    expect(wrapper.find(Button)).to.have.lengthOf(1);
})
})
```

My test output says
AssertionError: expected {} to have a length of 1 but got 0

1) The test fails. The Button component is not found in the test. I am expecting it to have a length of 1

2) I am using **chai** method *to.Have.lengthOf* because I could not get the **jest** method *toHaveLength* to work. *toHaveLength* seems to be used for only checking arrays or strings size. How could I use jest to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to simulate the `SignIn` form submit, you would actually call the `simulate` event on the form itself and not on the button.

You can simulate that with this code:

```
wrapper.find('form').simulate('submit');
```

Here is some info on why that is from the Enzyme docs:

> - Currently, event simulation for the shallow renderer does not    propagate as one would normally expect in a real environment. As a
>     result, one must call .simulate() on the actual node that has the
>     event handler set.
> - Even though the name would imply this simulates an actual event,    .simulate() will in fact target the component's prop based on the
>     event you give it. For example, .simulate('click') will actually get
>     the onClick prop and call it.
> - As noted in the function signature above passing a mock event is    optional. Keep in mind that if the code you are testing uses the
>     event for something like, calling event.preventDefault() or accessing 
>     any of its properties you must provide a mock event object with the
>     properties your code requires.

https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulate.html